# map numpy array by numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to map the values in an array by some other array which maps the values from that array to new values by index.

Example:

```
arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2])
tbl = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 2])
res = np.array([tbl[x] for x in arr])

print(arr)  # [0 1 2 3 0 4 3 3 1 4 0 0 0 2]
print(tbl)  # [0 1 1 0 2]
print(res)  # [0 1 1 0 0 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 1]
```

Is there a faster way to do this using numpy?

I am expecting `tbl` (and thus the number of different values in `arr`) to be very small (tens of values) but `arr` itself to be very large (millions of entries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing).

```
>>> tbl[arr]
[0 1 1 0 0 2 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 1]
```